# Compute new column by performing operation on float and datetime and timestamp index

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have df which has timestamp index, and i would like to create a new column such that i divide the float col1 value by the difference between 2 specific dates.
I have provided the command below, however i get the below error.
Can you please advise.

```
timestampindex       Floatcol1   OtherCols
2021-01-03 00:10:00    3.65  
2021-01-03 00:12:00    nan  
2021-01-03 00:15:00    3.65  


df['calc'] = df['floatnumbers'] / ((datetime(2021,10,21) - df.index.to_pydatetime()).days)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'days'


type(df.index)
Out[54]: pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
df['calc'] = df['floatnumbers'] / (pd.to_datetime('2021-10-21') - df.index).days)
```